# Using labview realtime module to catch .txt file in D disk

Tags: labview

How to use labview real-time module  to catch .txt file in D disk ?
I would like to use myRIO project.

Comment: my RIO does not have D Disk. Do you mean D disk of your pc?

Answer (score -1):

In case you are trying to open a file on your PC, as suggested by @Khachik,
I'd recommend reading this white paper: [Best Practices for Target File IO with LabVIEW Real-Time](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/10435/en/). The best solution to your problem depends on what you are trying to achieve.

An option could be to transfer your file to the target using [FTP](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/571113C2CE05998E862574E8006005A2) and then read it from your code, taking care of [properly formattig the path](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/14669/en/) depending on the Real Time operating system you have.